# Force HKEY_CURRENT_USER to update from HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-registry

I have a box that has settings for users at HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\ControlPanel\Accessibility. When a user logs onto that box, they are assigned these settings. The problem I am having is that two accounts that were used prior to this beings set in HKEY_USERS, do not get updated with these settings. Is there any way to force these other two accounts to use the settings from HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT, rather than what is in HKEY_CURRRENT_USER?

Comment: Create a Group policy or script that updates the `HKEY_CURRRENT_USER` as required instead of messing around with `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT`?

Comment: Or delete those user profiles and recreate them (not ideal but that would certainly do the trick).

Comment: Remove the setting you're trying to override from their existing hives

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So I could remove the whole HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Accessibility key to get the default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the user profiles that were affected (Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > User Profiles).

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that [the .Default user is not the default user](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/02/1786493.aspx)!

The `.Default` contains user configuration settings for the `SYSTEM` account, not the default registry values for new users.

When a key or setting is NOT present in the logged on users own HKCU hive, these settings apply, unless overridden by local or group policies for the user on that machine.

To force users to have a certain set of settings applied, use said policies.